# How can I check if an element exists in an if statement?

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium IDE for Chrome and I'm trying to click somewhere only if a specific element doesn't exist.

If I only wanted to do that, I can do it with an `assert`:

```
assert element not present    css=.something
click                         css=.button
```

However, this is part of a larger script and I want to continue with the rest of the script regardless of whether the element exists.

So I want to do something more like:

```
if          {something which means roughly "assert element not present"}
   click    css=.button
end
```

Is this possible? How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with i[f/endif](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs/selenium-ide/if) of the kantu [selenium ide](https://a9t9.com/kantu/):

```
verifyElementPresent (locator)
if | !{!statusOK}
 Click (...)
endIf
Script continues...
```

=> The "trick" here is to use [!statusOK](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs#!statusok) to check in the status of the last command. `${!statusOK}` here it will be true  if the element is found by [verifyElementPresent](http://verifyelementpresent). The `!` in front of the variable inverts this. *So the Click is reached when the element is **not** found.*

Answer (score 0):

Check out my update to [an older Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349435/selenium-ide-how-to-continue-script-on-element-not-found-or-on-error) on using Selenium 3 using store xpath count and if...end to execute code.

The basic idea:

store xpath count | css=.something | how_many_somethings
if | ${how_many_somethings} < 1
...magic stuff...
end

The other question has a screen shot and link to a full article.

Answer (score -1):

**Generically:**

```
try {
       waitForElementToBeVisible
       //Do nothing
} catch (ElementNotFound) { click }
```

**If no JavaScript wait is necessary:**

```
if( ! element.IsVisible()) click;
```

//Continue with your life ...

Comment: The question is about Selenium-IDE